# Any android application for field mapping with Google map in background

Tags: google-maps, cartography, android

I need a android/iPhone app, through which I can draw point/line/polygon while survey only. The app should have facility to use Google satellite imagery or provision for uploading base maps.
Please suggest, if any.

Comment: Survey-It https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.summit.simple_survey

Comment: @Mapperz I have tried your suggestion. This app is ok for marking some polygons on map, but I cant adjust polygon boundaries once after drawing and Adding another polygon is tedious. So please suggest any other app. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think ["My Maps" by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b&hl=en&rdid=com.google.android.apps.m4b) does exactly this. You can draw lines, areas, points, pictures, etc. It also seems that you can customize the look and share them. The same functionality is also available in a browser, by clicking (menu icon)-->"Your places"-->"MAPS" in [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps).

I have used it in the past for planning out parking, etc. for a large outdoor party, and I found it quite suitable.